# Can I store government ID numbers according to the PCI DSS?

Tags: pci-dss, credit-card, cloud-storage

I am developing a service, a part of which stores the credit card data of it's users. According to the Israeli credit card companies' requirements my users need to present their government ID number when making a transaction.

The PCI Standard prohibits the storage of CVV and credit card PIN numbers, because of information security reasons.

My question is, can I be sure that storing my users' government ID numbers is not against the PCI standard, since it serves almost the same purpose as a CVV or a PIN number - to verify the credit card holder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PCIDSS publishes how you store payment card data. A government Id is not covered.

However it probably is personally identifiable information and should still be handled with care.

The full set of requirements is buried in a pdf

https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/document_library?category=pcidss&document=pci_dss

But basically you have to encrypt the card number, and you cannot retain the CVV2 / PIN or any of the data you might read from a card (but that you can't see by looking at it)

Everything else is allowed to be stored unencrypted.

Comment: This is all true.  *However*, there might also be Israeli law which covers storing government ID#s.  It wouldn't be part of PCIDSS, but it would be applicable if operating in Israel.

Comment: Yes, you need to check the local Israeli laws on this matter, I can't read the Hebrew law text but there is an English news article about them locking down the ID number and not using it for this very purpose after a high profile attack in 2012: http://www.timesofisrael.com/new-rules-web-sites-cant-ask-for-id-numbers-unless-absolutely-necessary/

Comment: Thank you guys, I'll check the laws and requirements of my country and the credit card companies to see if they say something about it.